# Ordenar dados Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, classificação

Eu estou tentando ordenar minha busca por data, porém eu tenho que procurar um valor e não é permitido usar dois orderByChild. Eu preciso tanto encontrar o nome passado pela variável buscaNome quanto ordenar pela data de nascimento. Alguém poderia ajudar?

```
referenciaFirebase.child("cliente").orderByChild("nome").equalTo(buscaNome).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final String nomeCliente = postSnapshot.child("nome").getValue(String.class);

                    final String data_nascimento = postSnapshot.child("data").getValue(String.class);

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
```

Comment: Você tentou fazer o mesmo usando a classe Query ? Se não, tente usar ela no lugar de referenciaFirebase

Comment: Já sim, mas deu no mesmo